# Need help desiging an API wrapper for iOS / iPhone application

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios5

I'm currently building an iPhone app that needs to connect to an API. I built an API class that makes an async web request and uses a delegate to get the response (on the main UI thread). It looks something like this:

```
Api* api = [[Api alloc] init]
api.delegate = self;
[api request:@"foo/bar"]; // makes async API call via NSURLConnection

-(void) apiRespondedWith(id) response
{
    // do stuff with API response.
}
```

This works well, but I'd like to make several API requests in a ViewController and would like an easier way to distinguish between the calls. Is there a way to have specific callbacks for each API call made? Selectors or blocks seem like a way to do this, but I'm unsure of the best way to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this.  For example, you could perform the web request in an `NSOperation`/`NSOperationQueue`.  Note that if you use this approach the `NSURLConnection` will need to be performed synchronously inside the `NSOperation` - because the `NSOperation` is already executing asynchronously.  Each web download request is encapsulated in an `NSOperation` which, in turn, is submitted to an `NSOperationQueue`.

You can check out an [example](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/) of using `NSOperation`.

You could extend the example above by providing the `NSOperation` a completion block.

Alternatively, you could consider using a third-party library such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) which uses this sort of blocks-based callback mechanism.